# how to integrate DTCoreText into new project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-text

```
xcode 4.5.2

DTCoreText1.1
```

I have tried many methods ,but failed.
Anyone have experience about It?

how to integrate DTCoreText into new project?

I upload my file to www.uethink.com/test/DTCoreTextStudy.zip, anyone can edit it?

Comment: which methods have you tried and which are the errors?, in the [project github page](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) you can find step by step the way they recommend to setup the project in your own

Comment: yeah,I use the way they recommend,but always get error!

Comment: error: "DTVersion.h" not found!

Comment: or "DTHTMLParser.h" file not found

Comment: and I include DTFoundation in my project!

Comment: I upload my file to http://www.uethink.com/test/DTCoreTextStudy.zip

Answer (score 1):

Try using CocoaPods, integration will be really easy. No more include problems.

Answer (score 0):

there is some dependency on DTFoundation,

use Cocoapods or github to get DTCoreText

https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html